# Hadoop 2 (YARN). getting java.io.IOException: wrong key class. Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run hadoop 2 `MapReduce` process that the output_format_class is `SequenceFileOutputFormat` and the `input_format_class` is `SequenceFileInputFormat`.

I chose that the `Mapper` emits key and value both as `BytesWritable`. For the `Reducer` it emits key as `IntWritable` and value as `BytesWritable`.

Every time I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: wrong key class: org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:1306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I discovered that when I define the `OutputFormat` not as `SequenceFileOutputFormat` the problem is solved but I need it as a `SequenceFileOutputFormat`.

Here is the main:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);
    conf.set("refpath", "/out/Sample1/Local/EU/CloudBurst/BinaryFiles/ref.br");
    conf.set("qrypath",   "/out/Sample1/Local/EU/CloudBurst/BinaryFiles/qry.br");
    conf.set("MIN_READ_LEN",      Integer.toString(MIN_READ_LEN));
    conf.set("MAX_READ_LEN",      Integer.toString(MAX_READ_LEN));
    conf.set("K",                 Integer.toString(K));
    conf.set("SEED_LEN",          Integer.toString(SEED_LEN));
    conf.set("FLANK_LEN",         Integer.toString(FLANK_LEN));
    conf.set("ALLOW_DIFFERENCES", Integer.toString(ALLOW_DIFFERENCES));
    conf.set("BLOCK_SIZE",        Integer.toString(BLOCK_SIZE));
    conf.set("REDUNDANCY",        Integer.toString(REDUNDANCY));
    conf.set("FILTER_ALIGNMENTS", (FILTER_ALIGNMENTS ? "1" : "0"));

    Job job = new Job(conf,"CloudBurst");
    job.setNumReduceTasks(NUM_REDUCE_TASKS); // MV2

    //conf.setNumMapTasks(NUM_MAP_TASKS); TODO find solution for mv2

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/out/Sample1/Local/EU/CloudBurst/BinaryFiles/ref.br"));//TODO change it fit to the params
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/out/Sample1/Local/EU/CloudBurst/BinaryFiles/qry.br"));//TODO change it fit to the params

    job.setJarByClass(MerReduce.class);//mv2

    job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

    // The order of seeds is not important, but make sure the reference seeds are seen before the qry seeds
    job.setPartitionerClass(MerReduce.PartitionMers.class); // mv2
    job.setGroupingComparatorClass(MerReduce.GroupMersWC.class); //mv2 TODO

    job.setMapperClass(MerReduce.MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MerReduce.ReduceClass.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(BytesWritable.class);//mv2
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);//mv2
    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);

    Path oPath = new Path("/out/Sample1/Local/EU/Vectors");//TODO change it fit to the params
    //conf.setOutputPath(oPath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, oPath);
    System.err.println("  Removing old results");
    FileSystem.get(conf).delete(oPath);

    int code = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

    System.err.println("Finished");
}
```

The mapper class headline:

```
public static class MapClass extends Mapper<IntWritable, BytesWritable, BytesWritable, BytesWritable>
public void map(IntWritable id, BytesWritable rawRecord,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

The reducer class headline:

```
public static class ReduceClass extends Reducer (BytesWritable,  BytesWritable, IntWritable, BytesWritable)

public synchronized void reduce(BytesWritable mer, Iterator<BytesWritable> values,Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: will you provide your mapper class and reducer class also?

Comment: They are huge files. But the bottom line that the Mapper emits only key-values pairs as BytesWritable and BytesWritable. And the reducer emits only key-values pairs of IntWritable and BytesWtitable. If you would like I can add them. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. And what is your mapper extend line? Have you mentioned BytesWritable in extends mapper also? I think there it is IntWritable

Comment: ok. and reducer class first line is? Is it accepting the BytesWritable?
Just put your class first line and last context line for mapper and reducer classes

Comment: The stack trace in the error is saying that your Reducer is outputting a Key of type `BytesWritable`, which your Reduce code does not seem to be doing.  The stack trace also looks like your Reduce class is never being called.  Those hints together make me think maybe the configuration in your `main` is not correct in that the Reducer class is not properly set (although looking at the code you sent, it does look correct).

Answer (score 0):

```
job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
```

should be

job.setInputFormatClass(IntWritable.class);

You mapper input is int and bytes, but in job you gave both inputs as sequence